# Can't remove list of object in DB

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework

Hello i'm begginer and i'm working on a projet ASP.NET MVC 4 .

I have as table "Server" and "TypeServer", when i delete TypeServer, Server should be deleted too !

So using EF i added in the default code the code below but it doesn't work :

```
foreach (Serveur i in db.Serveurs.Where(s => idTypeServeur == s.idTypeServeur).ToList<Serveur>())
{
      Serveur serveur = db.Serveurs.Find(i.idServeur);
      db.Serveurs.Remove(serveur);
}
```

//Défault code

```
TypeServeur typeserveur = db.TypeServeurs.Find(idTypeServeur);
db.TypeServeurs.Remove(typeserveur);
db.SaveChanges();
return RedirectToAction("Index");
```

The exception :

> System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbUpdateException was unhandled by
>   user code   HResult=-2146233087   Message=An error occurred while
>   updating the entries. See the inner exception for details.
>   Source=EntityFramework

the problem is in the first code (foreach) but i tried too much things with no results !

Comment: *See the inner exception for details.* > So what does the inner exception say?

Comment: May be your typeserveur is null . please post inner exception

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can remove many with

```
db.Serveurs.Where(s => idTypeServeur == s.idTypeServeur)
           .ToList().ForEach(s => db.Serveurs.Remove(s));
var tServer = db.TypeServeur.Find(idTypeServeur);
db.TypeServeur.Remove(tServer);
 db.SaveChanges();
```

Comment: You are welcome @OussamaHafid see you on stackoverflow